# How do I convert an array in an XML attribute value to an Array object?

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an embedded xml file which I'd like to have a property like this:

```
<level missions="[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5]"/>
```

I'd like to know how can I convert the string value `[m1,m2,...]` into an array, in order to get its value by index (a[0] == "m1", a[1] == "m2", etc.)

I tried `Array(xml.levels.level.@missions)[0]`, but to no avail :)

Comment: it loads normaly. Maybe I should remove the `[]`s and just split the values by `,`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no E4X method to do directly process string array values like that.  You can use [String#split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) to convert the string value into an actual array:

```
var value:String = xml.levels.level.@missions.toString ();
var arr : Array = value.substr ( 1, value.length - 2 ).split ( "," );
```